# How to modifying the Search module (Drupal 7) to search also sub words

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I tried to modified the Search module to search also partial words. for example when 
I look for the word "Drupal" I want to be able to search: "drup" etc.

I tried to use the 'Fuzzy Search' module, but it is not good for me.
I found a patch file to add this option to the 'Search' module in Drupal 6 here:

https://drupal.org/node/103548

but my site is in Drupal 7.
Can someone give me a patch file for Drupal 7?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [finder module](https://drupal.org/project/finder) or [Apache Solr Search](https://drupal.org/project/apachesolr). But for Apache Solr Search you will need additional server configuration.

Comment: thanks for the answer. but at the end i succeeded to update the regular Search module to do that.